# Is it possible to have an object in the header of a DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, tostring

The question:
Do you guys know if there is any way that I can put an object in the header of a DataTable column, instead of an integer or a string?

Further explanation:
I'm writing a library that, in some moment, will read data from different meteorological stations. The data I'll read will be, for example, temperature, wind speed, atmospheric pressure, etc. These values can be read in different units (km/h, mph, celsius, fahrenheit) and the information about these units will be in a separate source, not together with the data itself. I'll be reading a XML file that will contain all the information about this datafile and, what I wanted to do is create an object with different attributes and use this object as the header of each column of the DataTable. A bit complicated explanation but I think that I was clear enough.

Do you think that it is possible using native .NET types or, if I wanted to do exactly this way I'd have to create my own table class?

Thank you all!

Comment: forget `DataTable`. Create a proper object model to represent your data. You can even load/save your XML data into objects via `Serialization` / `DeSerialization`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [DataColumn.ExtendedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datacolumn.extendedproperties.aspx) collection, which works like a dictionary and can hold any objects.

So every DataTable column can have an object associated with it, which have description of type, units and any other info.